# Where can I find the instructions for setting up SOLR without using IOC?

Tags: solr, dependency-injection

I'm trying to setup an instance of Sitecore 8.2 so I can see what it's going to take to upgrade my site from Sitecore 8.1 to it. I've heard that Sitecore 8.2 can run SOLR natively (without using IOC), but I can't find any documentation that tells me how to do it. All that I'm able to find are documents describing how to setup SOLR using IOC. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not tried to set this up yet myself, but I can tell you that the solr support package is no longer required. So, I'm going to guess that you can simply enable all of the solr files and disable the lucene files.

Comment: That seems to have worked for me. That actually seemed to be easier than I was expecting. Thanks!

Comment: No sweat! Here is a link to a simple script that will flip the configs back and forth. I haven't tested with 8.2, but it should work. https://gist.github.com/patrickperrone/59b8745ee8b8ff9045b5

Comment: That power shell script worked great for my test environment. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

In 8.2; SOLR support comes out of the box. You can optionally add your preferred DI container, but are not required to do so.

> The Sitecore Solr provider uses an IOC (Inversion of Control)
>   container so that all the elements inside it can be swapped without
>   re-compilation. **The default Sitecore installation includes a default
>   implementation of the Solr connector (SolrNet.dll).** If you need to use
>   another IOC, download the Solr support package for your version of
>   Sitecore from dev.sitecore.net (in the Additional tools section).

Source: [Walkthrough: Setting up Solr](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/80/setting_up__maintaining/search_and_indexing/walkthrough_setting_up_solr#_Configuring_an_IOC)